# Multiple aggregations in the PIVOT function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying to use multiple aggregations in the PIVOT function in SQL Server. Currently I have used SUM which is working as expected, I wanted to use AVG also along with SUM. I saw some sample queries but they were too long. Can anyone help me to modify the below query to include AVG of SubTotal for each PaymentMethod and each year.

```
    SELECT PaymentMethod, [2016], [2015]
FROM (SELECT PaymentMethod, SubTotal, YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR]
      FROM [TransactionDetails]) AS sq 
PIVOT(SUM(SubTotal) FOR [YEAR] 
IN([2016], [2015])) AS Pvt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any way of doing this besides running two completely separate `PIVOT`s based, each time, on the original source data.

So I've moved the subselect into a CTE to avoid repeating its definition and then I'm joining the two pivoted results base on the `PaymentMethod`:

```
declare @t table (PaymentMethod varchar(30) not null, SubTotal int not null, 
                  OrderDate date not null)
insert into @t(PaymentMethod,SubTotal,OrderDate) values
('Cash',10,'20150101'), ('Cash',20,'20151231'),
('Cash',30,'20160101'), ('Cash',90,'20161231')

;With ToBePivoted as (
    SELECT PaymentMethod, SubTotal, YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR]
    FROM @t
)
SELECT s.PaymentMethod, s.[2016],a.[2016], s.[2015], a.[2015]
FROM
    ToBePivoted tbp1
    PIVOT(SUM(SubTotal) FOR [YEAR] IN([2016], [2015])) AS s
    inner join
    ToBePivoted tbp2
    pivot(AVG(SubTotal) FOR [YEAR] IN([2016],[2015])) AS a
    ON
        s.PaymentMethod = a.PaymentMethod
```

Result:

```
PaymentMethod                  2016        2016        2015        2015
------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Cash                           120         60          30          15
```

The problem here is that a) We want to use different aggregates (not allowed within a single `PIVOT`) and b) that a `PIVOT` "uses up" the columns mentioned in the first part of the `PIVOT`. This means that after the first `PIVOT`, there aren't any columns containing the years any more to allow the second pivot to be directly applied.

Comment: You are great. Thank you so much. In my case, I have more than 5 aggregated columns, but still your logic looks simpler.